# seaborn scatterplot x/y ticks datatype are switched (float values to int, and vice versa)

Tags: floating-point, integer, seaborn, scatter-plot, xticks

I'm using seaborn scatterplot to plot engine 'liter' values (float) vs engine 'cylinder' values (integer).

[image: seaborn scatterplot liter vs cylinder]

- There are three 'cylinder' values- 4, 6, and 8. However the ticks for cylinders on the scatterplot appear as floats- 4.0, 4.5, 5.0, 5.5, 6.0, etc. (x-axis)
- The 'liters' values are floats- 1.8, 2.5, 3.1, 4.6, etc. But the ticks on the scatterplot appear as integers- 2, 3, 4, etc. (y-axis)

Why is this? And how do I switch it so that 'liter' ticks are in floats and the 'cylinder' ticks are in integers.

Comment: maybe a [`catplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html) be a better option for plotting this data?

Comment: Ah, Thanks. While this is better, it is still breaking down the cylinder values into decimals. Is there a way to control the ticks?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're doing, but I can make up some data and plot it with:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

cyl = np.random.choice([4,6,8], 30)

data = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    Cylinder=cyl, 
    Liter=np.random.normal(2 + cyl * 0.5, 0.2),
))

sns.catplot(x='Liter', y='Cylinder', data=data, orient="h")
```

gives me:
[image: plot]

Note that you might also need to convert your Cylinder data to integers, e.g. with:

```
data = data.astype({'Cylinder': int})
```